# I can't get this simple c++ script to compile. Any ideas?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Im learning c++ and am a noob at it any help would be nice. :)
please
   This is a text based rpg that im messing with. Making a rpg is a great way to learn a language. But any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int health, armor, damage;
    health = 100;
    armor = 0;
    damage = 5;// This is a dynamic var for desision making
    int loopcon = 1;
    int decision = 1; 

    cout << "You enter the forest and have no idea what has happened and your head hurts.\n";
    cout << "You are trying to remember whaT happened to you and how you ended up here but you cant.\n";
    cout << "You see a town would you like to explore it?";
    cout << "What is your name?";
    while (loopcon == 1) {
        cout << "1/0";
        cin >> decision;
        if (decision == 1) 
            cout << "You enter the city";
        if (decision == 0)
            cout << "Theres also a forsest want to export that?";

        else
            cout << "try useing caps";

    }    


    return 0;
}
```

when I run this is get a big long error any ideas?

```
sudo gcc maingame.cpp
/tmp/cca53Qhv.o: In function `main':
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `std::cout'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `std::cout'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `std::cout'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `std::cout'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `std::cout'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `std::cin'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `std::cout'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `std::cout'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `std::cout'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/tmp/cca53Qhv.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
maingame.cpp:(.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Its to long so ill send it in paste bin. http://pastebin.com/sraW6Cry

Comment: woops fixed that error and it made the error I just sent

Comment: Why do you change your code from what the original was? The answers won't make sense if the problem no longer exists in the posted code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You commented out the standard namespace... Change

```
//using namespace std;
```

to

```
using namespace std;
```

Edit: your compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong... It can't find a reference to the std namespace functions because you haven't declared it. But note that it is [bad practice to be declaring it globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice). When you gain more familiarity with the language you should be declaring the namespace manually using the scope resultion `::` operator.

Comment: Worth mentioning [Why is “using namespace std” in C++ considered bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you commented `using namespace std;` but kept using some of its references (`cout` and `cin`) without explicitly stating which namespace they come from (eq `std::cout`).

Solution:

Add `std::` to all your `cout`s and `cin`s because [using “using namespace std” in C++ is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Code compiles and has no problem. Check your IDE (compiler). And for the record, always **state** what is the error!

Comment: Glad we were able to help. :)